# ModuleNotFoundError running Python Script as systemd task

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, python, mqtt

I have a Python script which I'd like to run at startup. However when I run it as a systemd service, it seems to be unable to find one of the modules. Here's the status message:

```
● mqttproc.service - MQTT Post-processor
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mqttproc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-06 11:10:45 GMT; 2min 31s ago
    Process: 2375 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ken/python/mqttproc/mqttproc.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2375 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 06 11:10:45 MintVM systemd[1]: Started MQTT Post-processor.
Dec 06 11:10:45 MintVM python3[2375]: Sensor positions [100.0, 80.0, 60.0, 40.0, 20.0, 0.0] (Litres)
Dec 06 11:10:45 MintVM python3[2375]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 06 11:10:45 MintVM python3[2375]:   File "/home/ken/python/mqttproc/mqttproc.py", line 131, in <module>
Dec 06 11:10:45 MintVM python3[2375]:     import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
Dec 06 11:10:45 MintVM python3[2375]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'
Dec 06 11:10:45 MintVM systemd[1]: mqttproc.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 06 11:10:45 MintVM systemd[1]: mqttproc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The bizarre thing is this script runs without fail from the commandline. I even have it running as a systemd service on another machine. My .service file is as simple as they come:

```
[Unit]
Description=MQTT Post-processor

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ken/python/mqttproc/mqttproc.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/ken/python/mqttproc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can anyone point out the obvious thing I'm missing, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Comment: @KDM This is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you have another question Ask it.

Comment: How did you install the `paho` python module?

Comment: Usual. But I think my answer is in the fact that it was installed for a specific user (not root) environment. Thanks.